# 1054 unknown column django after south migration

Tags: python, django

Have sync my app and db with south.

The database is old and I want to add some new columns.

```
1: python manage.py convert_to_south myappName

2: python manage.py schemamigration myappName --auto

3: python manage.py migrate myappName --fake (did use for a table, but not the 
   table that is the problem)

4: python manage.py migrate myappName
```

Everything looks nice, app is synced an everything.

But i still get 1054....

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you running a fake migration? Are you aware of what that means?

Comment: @melwil, because he said he already has a syncronized database for the app in question.

Comment: Yes, as @Hedde wrote, had a old table that south said alreday exits.

Comment: Sorry, south workflow has changed since I installed south on an old project. ./manage.py convert_to_south myappName would fix the faking as well on the machine that runs it. You only have to do fake migrations on other machines. As far as I can understand from http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you create a initial migration after you added a column to your model, but before its actually appears in the database.

The correct workflow should be following:

1) Have a working django app that don't throw any unknown column. ( comment out the new columns)

2) Do your step 1-4

3) Then you need to add the columns you want and run your step 2 ( schemamigration myappName --auto) once more.

4) Then you need to run migrate command.

Thats all

Comment: Heureka! Finaly! It works. Your answer was great. Had to remove and add some columns, but finaly it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I followed this exactly and received a 1054 error after I uploaded the models function with new attributes and then ran schemamigration myappName --auto

Comment: yep same here. Still having a 1054 after uncommenting my field while I'm running the schemamigration :(