# I'm adding columns to my mysql database - Migrating my database to south

Tags: mysql, database, django, django-south, migrate

I have a mysql database. I want to add more columns, so I'm starting to use south. I want to set my database up to use south. How do I do this?

I followed the steps at [1054 unknown column django after south migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419235/1054-unknown-column-django-after-south-migration) to no avail

**NO CHANGES TO MODELS YET**

```
(venv)sfo-mpmgr:summertime msmith$ python manage.py convert_to_south livestream
Creating migrations directory at '/Users/msmith/Documents/dj/summertime/livestream/migrations'...
Creating __init__.py in '/Users/msmith/Documents/dj/summertime/livestream/migrations'...
 + Added model livestream.Stream
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate livestream
 - Soft matched migration 0001 to 0001_initial.
Running migrations for livestream:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > livestream:0001_initial
   (faked)

App 'livestream' converted. Note that South assumed the application's models matched the database
(i.e. you haven't changed it since last syncdb); if you have, you should delete the livestream/migrations
directory, revert models.py so it matches the database, and try again.



(venv)sfo-mpmgr:summertime msmith$ python manage.py schemamigration livestream --auto
Nothing seems to have changed.


(venv)sfo-mpmgr:summertime msmith$ python manage.py migrate livestream --fake
Running migrations for livestream:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for livestream.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)


(venv)sfo-mpmgr:summertime msmith$ python manage.py migrate livestream
Running migrations for livestream:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for livestream.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

**Now I update the Models with the new attribute.**

```
(venv)sfo-mpmgr:summertime msmith$ python manage.py schemamigration livestream --auto
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'livestream_stream.step' in 'field list'")
```

Anyone know how to avoid this error?